# cordova 2.1 plugin development

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to develop a plugin for cordova version 2.1. In 2.1 version, I understand we need to give the Plugin name in a dictionary in corodova.plist. The value will be the plugin name(i.e) the class name. What should be the key?

Comment: Cordova 2.1 is deprecated. There is no support available for it any longer. This is not to say, you cannot develop for it. It is to say there is no help available. Best of Luck.

Comment: You can't submit cordova 2.1 apps to play store or app store due to security reasons. Anyway, you can read old docs http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.1.0/guide/plugin-development/index.html